# visual studio typescript conflict with angular 2

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, angular, visual-studio-2015

I've just started a new project to develop an application with angular 2 and type script with visual studio  2015 ( update 3) but I got an error :
"tsc.exe exited with code 2".
when I open my project properties I can't config typescript from there and the error is  "one or more tsconfig.json files detected."
[image]
I think maybe the reason is bunch of  tsconfig.json files in node_modules sub folders so I excluded the node_modules folder in my tsconfig.json but  it seems VS can not find and use my tsconfig.json.
Actually after some hours wasting my time correcting this now I have no idea how to fix this and run a simple angular 2 project with typescript in visual studio.
any idea about how to solve this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the detailled output? Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Compile and Run and set the MS Build Project output to detailled. Now build once again and check if you can get some more details out of the output. I had that error multiple times before - appeared mostly because Visual wanted to compile 3rd party angular libs, although I excluded them via my tsconfig file..

Comment: @fen89 I want to exclude them with my tsconfig but the problem is that vs can not find my tsconfig and I think the problem is multiple tsconfigs exists in the angular libs.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to error described here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Common%20Errors

Check that your file encoding is UTF-8.